# raw issue in android MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

I have an issue about button sounds. I can't use "raw" even if I create the folder in "res" folder (res/raw). Eclipse asks me if I wanna create that in R file....is it convinient?? please help. Any help would be aprecciate.

The idea is that when I click a ImageButton sound the color of the Image.

```
  MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
  public void dos(View v) {
    TextView f = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pts);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color);
    c++;
    if (t.getText().toString().equals("YELLOW")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pts++;
        color(v);
        mp1.start();
        f.setText(Integer.toString(pts));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}
```

The only problem is in this line

```
MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
```

raw is underlined and it says that need to create the field or constant in R file.

Comment: Are you importing the correct Resource class? It should be something like <packageName>.R

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this :

```
MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
```

With this:

```
`final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);`
```